# Error: $parse:syntax Syntax Error with ng-submit

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

### Access dynamic form object in controller

Is there a way to access a form object in controller by just passing the name?

I have dynamic forms inside my html which has name like `name="namedForm_{{$index}}"`.

Now I can pass the `$index` in `ng-submit` function call to generate form name in controller. So it will be `namedForm_1` or `namedForm_2`, etc. How to get the form object in controller to check the form validity there?

Tried passing the validity as third argument here by checking condition. But the expression `namedForm_{{$index}}.$valid` is breaking.

```
<form data-toggle="validator" class="formClass" form-submit-validation=""
      name="namedForm_{{$index}}" id="namedForm_{{$index}}"
      ng-submit="namedForm_{{$index}}.$valid == true ? vm.submitNamedForm($index, widget, true) : vm.submitNamedForm($index, widget, false)"
      autocomplete="off" novalidate>
</form>
```

Or any other solutions?

Error from console:

[image: error]

Comment: I believe you need to use `ng-form` for that

Comment: @AlekseySolovey `ng-form` is for nested form right? My requirement is to have just dynamic forms and validating it.
Like `<form></form><form></form>`

Comment: no, it's an additional form for dynamic names and their validations

Comment: Any sample to use it in this way (non-nested)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use property accessor on `this` context:

```
<form data-toggle="validator" class="formClass" form-submit-validation=""
      name="namedForm_{{$index}}" id="namedForm_{{$index}}"
      ̶n̶g̶-̶s̶u̶b̶m̶i̶t̶=̶"̶n̶a̶m̶e̶d̶F̶o̶r̶m̶_̶{̶{̶$̶i̶n̶d̶e̶x̶}̶}̶.̶$̶v̶a̶l̶i̶d̶ ̶=̶=̶ ̶t̶r̶u̶e̶ ̶?̶ ̶v̶m̶.̶s̶u̶b̶m̶i̶t̶N̶a̶m̶e̶d̶F̶o̶r̶m̶(̶$̶i̶n̶d̶e̶x̶,̶ ̶w̶i̶d̶g̶e̶t̶,̶ ̶t̶r̶u̶e̶)̶ ̶:̶ ̶v̶m̶.̶s̶u̶b̶m̶i̶t̶N̶a̶m̶e̶d̶F̶o̶r̶m̶(̶$̶i̶n̶d̶e̶x̶,̶ ̶w̶i̶d̶g̶e̶t̶,̶ ̶f̶a̶l̶s̶e̶)̶"̶
      ng-submit="vm.submitNamedForm($index, widget, this['namedForm_'+$index].$valid)"
      autocomplete="off" novalidate>
</form>
```

The `ng-submit` directive requires an AngularJS expression and it is not wise to mix interpolation `{{ }}` with Angular expressions.

For more information, see

- [AngularJS Error Reference - $parse:syntax](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$parse/syntax)
- [AngularJS Developer Guide - Expression Context](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#context)
- [AngularJS Developer Guide - Why mixing interpolation and expressions is bad practice](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/interpolation#why-mixing-interpolation-and-expressions-is-bad-practice-)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation!